# Stdio.h on VC++6.0

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{   

        printf("HelloWorld\n");

        return 0;
}
```

It appeared a series of errors when I clicked build button. But there
is not any problem when i substituted "stdlib.h" for "stdio.h".

```
d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(84) : error C2059: syntax error : ','

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '__cdecl'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2081: 'FILE' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(314) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '__cdecl'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2081: 'FILE' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(320) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(341) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(342) : error C2059: syntax error : ','

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(342) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'const'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(342) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(342) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'const'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(342) : error C2059: syntax error : ','

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(342) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(352) : error C2059: syntax error : ','

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(352) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'const'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(352) : error C2081: 'size_t' : name in formal parameter list illegal

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(352) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before 'const'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(352) : error C2059: syntax error : ','

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(352) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'

d:\program files (x86)\vc++ 6.0\vc6.0\vc98\include\stdio.h(403) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Comment: For your next question, remember to indent code blocks by 4 spaces (easy way here is select the code and hit `ctrl`+`k`). Also `<!-- language: none -->` is useful for console output dumps, see my final edit. Sorry for interfering with your edits, that wasn't intentional.

Comment: Is there really a compelling reason for you to actually use MSVC6.0?

Comment: MSVC6.0 was released in 98 (as the directory name tells). It is old enough to drink or vote in most jurisdictions.

Comment: Something is probably messed up with your VS6 installation, your code compiles fine with my VS6.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to compile C code with a C++ compiler.

One way round this with Visual Studio 6.0 is to rename the source file to take a `.c`, rather than a `.cpp` extension. That puts the compiler into a sort of "C" mode.

Comment: Haven't used Visual C++ 6 in ages, but as far as I remember this should be a non-issue header wise. Right now I'd suspect some preprocessor define to screw up the header file's syntax.

Comment: @Mario: I can't verify this either, this is all from memory, but it's what I used to do to get this compiler to build C code.

Comment: As far as I remember all bundled standard headers have proper optional `#extern "C"` brackets around them. Also if it would be some C/C++ conflict, it would more likely show as a linking error rather than syntax.

Comment: @Mario why should `stdio.h` be designed to be usable from C++? I think you're supposed to include `cstdio` instead for C++?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Because VC6 has been very messy. You're supposed to, but both should work. Using the explicit `cstdio` header you basically just include `stdio.h` and then fix up some of the mappings (e.g. global namespace vs. `std` namespace). I remember using both pretty much interchangeably. It's certainly not clean nor recommended, but it worked.

Comment: VS6 compiles .cpp files that #include standard C header files such as stdio.h.